# need to get matching records after $lookup and $match in mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup, aggregation

Aggregation Query:

```
db.status.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "order",
      "localField": "orderId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "output"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "output.status": "PICKUP_COMPLETE"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "orderId": 1,
      "orderStatus": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$orderStatus",
          "as": "orderStatus",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$orderStatus.status", "PICKUP_COMPLETE"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Status collection record:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("59490963d683587d32c278ac"),
  "orderId": ObjectId("5949095ed683587d32c278a9"),
  "tenantId": "D-mart",
  "orderStatus": [
    {
      "status": "ESTIMATES_RECEIVED",
      "updatedAt": "June 20th 2017, 6:39:15 am"
    },
    { "status": "RECEIVED_BY_LMA", "updatedAt": "June 20th 2017, 6:45:25 am" },
    { "status": "ORDER_CONFIRMED", "updatedAt": "June 20th 2017, 6:45:25 am" }
  ]
}
```

I need to get all matching records from order collection and status collection, based on orderId field, and match records which have status as "PICKUP_COMPLETE" in orderStatus array(any one array object should have this status).

The above query is working fine, joining the two collections based on orderId, but it only returns the first matching record. i.e.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a7e0a06a33f4900015c14d7"),
  "orderId": ObjectId("5a7e0a06a33f4900015c14d6"),
  "orderStatus": [
    {
      "status": "PICKUP_COMPLETE",
      "updatedAt": "February 14th 2018, 11:51:09 am"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to know how to get the whole list of such matching records...

Comment: Remove the `$match` condition should work?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, that would return the records for other statuses too. I want the records that specifically have status as PICKUP_COMPLETE, after joining the collections

Comment: Could you post the sample collection from the `order` collection as well. And the expected output as well

Comment: I am just using the "_id" field of order collection to map with orderId of status collection. Unable to post sample, since it's too long...

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.4.18

Comment: Your aggregation should work. Not sure what else do you need

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, the aggregation is working fine. The issue is, that it's just returning the FIRST matching record, whereas i want all the matching records...